# regex, find xml node which has certain subnodes (In Sublime Text)

Tags: xml, regex, sublimetext, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for the regular expression (for Sublime Text) to select xml elemets which have a certain sub-element.
I can select all the elements with this:

```
(?s)<wp:comment>.+?</wp:comment>
```

This works perfect but I want to find the blocks which contain

```
<wp:comment_approved>0</wp:comment_approved>
```

And not which contain:

```
<wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
```

So I need a lookaraound (look ahead or look behind) or conditional expression, but I cant get it right.
When I try:

```
(?s)<wp:comment>.+?comment_approved>1.+?</wp:comment>
```

It selects more elements in one select than it should.

It seems very simple but I cant find the right answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this would work:

```
(?s)<wp:comment>(?:(?!<wp:comment>).)+?+<wp:comment_approved>0.+?+</wp:comment>
```

Note the possessive matching (`.+?+`) to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: It dit not work but i ajusted it to:

(?s)<wp:comment>(?:(?!<wp:comment>).)+?<wp:comment_approved>0.+?</wp:comment>

And this works, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Mh, I was not sure whether Sublime Text supports possessive quantifiers. Maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Oke, the answer to the problem explained. 
Find only the comments which are not approved.

```
<xml>
    <node>bla</node>
    <wp:comment>
        <node>bla</node>
        <node>bli</node>
        <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
        <node></node>
        <node></node>
    </wp:comment>
    <wp:comment>
        <node>ble</node>
        <node>blu</node>
        <wp:comment_approved>0</wp:comment_approved>
        <node></node>
        <node></node>
    </wp:comment>
</xml>
```

This is the syntax for regex find in the xml in Sublime Text:

```
(?s)<wp:comment>(?:(?!<wp:comment>).)+?<wp:comment_approved>0.+?</wp:comment>

(?s)           -> global search and multiline
<wp:comment>   -> find occurrence
(?: ... )      -> group but do not capture submatch 
(?! ... )      -> negative lookahead
<wp:comment>(?:(?!<wp:comment>).)+? 
               -> find <wp:comment> plus everything 
                  until a new <wp:comment> starts. 
                  This is for not select two or more comments 
                  in one time.
<wp:comment_approved>0.+?</wp:comment> 
               -> then find '<wp:comment_approved>0' 
                  Plus everything, then find </wp:comment>.
```

So:

first find the start (main pattern) then

find everything but not a new start

find the sub pattern

find the rest

find the end (main pattern)